# MySQL bulk INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE while specifying individual columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to bulk insert thousands of rows if a table from 2 different cronjobs with different datasets, I'm currently using `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

Considering the first value is the unique key to check for duplicates,

First cronjob would for example run (from data source 1):

```
INSERT INTO `places` () VALUES
 ('aaa', 'bbb', NULL),
 ('ccc', NULL, 'ddd')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE;
```

Second cronjob would for example run (from data source 2):

```
INSERT INTO `places` () VALUES
 ('aaa', NULL, 'eee'),
 ('ccc', 'ddd', 'fff')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

As you can see, the second cronjob would overwrite valid values from the first cronjob with `null` values, which I don't want.
If I remove the `null` values from the data, the query would break as there would be a data mismatch.

The only solutions I can think of is to execute LOTS of single insert/updates, which would be slower.

If I could do a bulk

```
INSERT INTO `places` VALUES
 (column1='aaa', column3='eee'),
 (column1='ccc', column2='ddd', column3='fff')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

then I wouldn't have to worry about keys anyone else but I don't think it's possible in MySQL.. does anyone know of a better way to do this?

Comment: if you only care about the primary key... just use insert ignore

Comment: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-ignore/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548541/insert-ignore-vs-insert-on-duplicate-key-update

Comment: I can't insert ignore unfortunately. Cronjob 2 might have the data missing from cronjob 1 so it should complete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the following and it seems to work:

```
INSERT INTO `places` (col1, col2, col3) VALUES
 ('aaa', NULL, 'eee'),
 ('ccc', 'ddd', 'fff')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
 col1=COALESCE(VALUES(col1), col1),
 col2=COALESCE(VALUES(col2), col2),
 col3=COALESCE(VALUES(col3), col3);
```

In an ON DUPLICATE KEY statement, the `VALUES(<col>)` means "whatever I tried to insert in each row." So in the first row above, `VALUES(col2)` is NULL, and `col2` is the value already stored on the row for that primary key.

The `COALESCE()` function returns its first non-NULL argument. So `COALESCE(NULL, col2)` returns the existing value for `col2`.

You do need to write out all the clauses for all these columns if you want to have them "default to previous" in this way.

P.S.: Your use of `INSERT INTO places ()` is incorrect. The empty list of columns `()` must correspond to an empty list of values. I.e. the two lists must have the same number of terms.

Comment: COALESCE!!! How did I not think of that! Thanks friend :) Thanks the extra tip on my mistake!